# How to create Nested Accordion in Drupal 7?

Tags: navigation

2015

-- Jan

-- Feb

```
  -- Link 1

  -- Link 2
```

2014

-- Jan

-- Feb

```
  -- Link 1

  -- Link 2
```

I want same views accordion feature on this listing with expand or collapse feature .

First user select year then month then we show the node title according to month & year .

Comment: Have you loookup https://www.drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu ?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal View Accordion triggers the accordion for the innermost Group Header. Though Nested Grouping can be done but the accordion effect will only applied to inner group.

For this we have to apply our own JS. I have created a module in which current accordion plugin has been extended, which itself was extending view plugin style. And additional setting has been added to it for nested accordion.

I have committed a [[D7] Views Nested Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/node/2304891) module on sandbox for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use module [Views Accordion](https://drupal.org/project/views_accordion).

Project page says:

> Views Accordion provides a display style plugin for the Views module.
>   It will take the results and display them as a JQuery accordion, using
>   the first field as the header for the accordion rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the nested feature is available as a module yet.

There is this module though: https://drupal.org/project/views_accordion

I've used it in single level accordions.

Then to nest it you could try this JQuery UI widget: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Just edit your view so it will display the clickable items inside each row of your view as headers.

---

Though if you want to go expert mode, you can just use http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

slidetoggle is pretty easy, just include a javascript file then use the jquery commands:

`$('#header1').click( function(){
 $(this).sibling('.content').slideToggle();
});`

Or something like that.